# MONGODB [DEBUG] cursor.refresh() for cursor 7078636577051629992

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid, mlab

While updating a big json list, I'm getting the following error :

```
2012-04-01T09:34:00+00:00 app[run.1]: MONGODB [DEBUG] cursor.refresh() for cursor 7078636577051629992
2012-04-01T09:34:00+00:00 app[run.1]: the server responded with status 404
2012-04-01T09:34:00+00:00 app[run.1]: rake aborted!
```

That seems to say:   in consequence of cursor.refresh() I get a time out then the server 404 responce

Mongodb is currently running on Heroku/MongoLAB but on my local machine I've not this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answer on Google group of Mongoid by Durran Jordan ( Mongoid's creator ) ( https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongoid/n8pWIVBaYMI/discussion )

You try using [Mopped](http://github.com/mongoid/moped) and it's not currently production ready.