# mongo slow query, cursor.refresh?

Tags: mongodb

I got a set of 20 queries that each one (according to log takes 5 ms) and that fine by me,
between the queries the log shoe me this line 
"MONGODB [DEBUG] cursor.refresh() for cursor 21910540893136"
and it takes a while (few seconds) for this operation to end.

what is this cursor refresh ? can I avoid it? or invoke it late?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Queries to MongoDB return a cursor, which can be iterated to retrieve
>   results

The cursor refresh occurs when there are too many results to be fetched from mongodb. I suspect that it is the driver's responsibility to handle this, so the answer is probably no, you cannot avoid it.

You can find more information about cursors [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors#QueriesandCursors-LatentCursorsandSnapshotting).

Comment: I got something similar here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963599/mongodb-debug-cursor-refresh-for-cursor-7078636577051629992